# Is there a way to inject a dependency that will use a specific bean depending on where it's injected (with Spring boot)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I've got a service (let's call it `TaskExecutorService`), that requires a dependency `TaskService`.
I'm used to inject dependency through constructor, so I've go the following code:

```
@Service
class TaskExecutorService {
  private final TaskService taskService;

  public TaskExecutorService(TaskService taskService) {
     this.taskService = taskService;
  }

  void function1() {...}
  void function2() {...}
}
```

The `TaskService` have a dependency `TaskRetrieverService` which is an interface, implemented by multiple "retrievers" annotated with @Service.

```
@Service
class TaskService {
  private final TaskRetrieverService taskRetrieverService;

  public TaskService(TaskRetrieverService taskRetrieverService) {
     this.taskRetrieverService = taskRetrieverService;
  }
}
```

What's the best way to inject the `TaskService` in `TaskExecutorService` choosing which retriever to use?
Moreover, my real use case is that depending on the function in `TaskExecutorService` (`function1` or `function2`), I'd like to be able to use either a "retriever" or another.

I think I could instantiate the `TaskService` directly in the methods using its constructor but I hope that there's a best way to do this.

Comment: Wouldn't that make it inversion of inversion of control? Therefore just instantiating it directly would be the straight forward way to go.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I agree with the kind of anti pattern

Comment: I posted my solution. This way you don't need to hardcode anything with `new`, but depending on the function (`function1` or `function2`) you use at runtime, you can just choose one interface implementation or the other. 

I still agree this is kind of an anti pattern, now I just use Spring as intermediary so I don't need to "hardcode" the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I agree this is some kind on anti pattern as you're wiring the `@Bean`, but I've needed to do this a couple of times and there's no obligation to hardcode the interface implementation.

The answer is, you can name your beans when you declare them at your Spring Config with `@Bean(name = "customName")`. This way, you can choose which *interface implementation* you're going to use.

For the following example (based on your case), I have an interface dependency called `Dependency.java`. For this example, let's keep it simple so it just has one method `print()`, which will print something depending on the implementation we're using at runtime.

```java
public interface Dependency {
    void print();
}
```

I have two possible implementations for this dependency. Those are `Child1` and `Child2`.

This is `Child1.java`

```java
public class Child1 implements Dependency {
    @Override
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("I'm Child1!");
    }
}
```

This is `Child2.java`

```java
public class Child2 implements Dependency {
    @Override
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("I'm Child2!");
    }
}
```

As you see, they only implement from our `Dependency.java` and do nothing else. They implement the method, which prints an statement to differentiate which one is being implemented at *runtime*.

Then I have a Spring Config class called `SpringConfig.java`

```java
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("you.packages.go.here.for.discovery.**.*")
public class SpringConfig {

    @Bean(name = "myBean1")
    public Dependency dependency() {
        return new Child1();
    }

    @Bean(name = "myBean2")
    public Dependency dependency2() {
        return new Child2();
    }

}
```

Here I have my 2 beans declared, each one with an **unique name**. The first implementation (`Child1`), for this example, will be called `myBean1` and the second implementation (`Child2`) will be `myBean2`.

Then I have the `@Service` class which will use one of those two `@Beans`. **Instead of a hardwire with `new Child1()`, I use Spring to wire the `Context` here**. This way I can choose which one I want to choose, depending on logic.

```java
@Service
public class MyService implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private ApplicationContext context;

    public void useDependency() {
        Dependency dependency = (Dependency) context.getBean("myBean2");
        dependency.print();
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        this.context = applicationContext;
    }
}
```

The context is being implemented by `implements ApplicationContextAware`. This adds the `setApplicationContext()` method which holds the `ApplicationContext`. Once you have this *context* you just need to choose which of the *interface* implementations are you going to use with the previous line

```
Dependency dependency = (Dependency) context.getBean("myBean2");
```

If you change `myBean2` for `myBean1` *(or any other name you set at `SpringConfig`'s parameter `@Bean(name = "something")`* you will change the runtime implementation to that `@Bean`).

I implemented the `@Bean` `myBean2`, so as expected, this will print

> "I'm Child2!"

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this.

// Quick typing, not tested, please ignore typo or incorrect syntax. I think you can get the idea.

```
@Service class TaskExecutorService {
  private final TaskService taskService;

  @Autowired
  public TaskExecutorService(TaskService taskService) {
     this.taskService = taskService;
  }

  void function1() {
      taskService.getTaskRetrieverService(RetrieverType.FIRST).doSomething();
  }
  void function2() {
      taskService.getTaskRetrieverService(RetrieverType.SECOND).doSomething();
  }
}

@Service
class TaskService {
  private final TaskRetrieverService firstTaskRetrieverService;
  private final TaskRetrieverService secondTaskRetrieverService;

  @Autowired
  public TaskService(
     TaskRetrieverService firstTaskRetrieverService, //param name matter or use @Qualifier
     TaskRetrieverService secondTaskRetrieverService //param name matter or use @Qualifier
  ) {
     this.firstTaskRetrieverService = firstTaskRetrieverService;
     this.secondTaskRetrieverService = secondTaskRetrieverService;
  }

  public TaskRetrieverService getTaskRetrieverService(RetrieverType retrieverType) {
     switch (retrieverType) {
         case RetrieverType.FIRST:
             return this.firstTaskRetrieverService;
         case RetrieverType.SECOND:
             return this.secondTaskRetrieverService;
         default:
             return this.firstTaskRetrieverService;
     }
  }
}

@Service
class FirstTaskRetrieverService implements TaskRetrieverService {
    void doSomething() {
    }
}

@Service
class SecondTaskRetrieverService implements TaskRetrieverService {
    void doSomething() {
    }
}
```